# How can I create a dependency graph in Visual Studio programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dependency-graph

In Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate (and also 2010 and 2013), one can generate a dependency graph using ARCHITECTURE -> For Solution. I would like to access this functionality programmatically, perhaps using the Visual Studio SDK.

How can this be done?

P.S.
I'm aware of GraphCmd.exe. However, I need to be able to generate graphs for C/C++/C# projects and make certain modifications and calculations on said graphs.

EDIT:

I would specifically like to access the graph data structure produced by the dependency graph tool in VS.

Comment: You should probably ask a more specific question. This is like asking how to do a whole project (which you could probably charge for!).

Comment: Alright. I added a specific goal.